# How to provide Id or Attribute to the react components

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, kendo-ui, custom-data-attribute

We need to provide some identifier for our react components so that we can do the automation test case writing on those controls.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Grid, GridColumn as Column } from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';

import products from './products.json';

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        gridData: products
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Grid
                    data-grid="myGrid"
                    style={{ height: '400px' }}
                    data={this.state.gridData}
                >
                    <Column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="40px" />
                    <Column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="200px" />
                    <Column field="Category.CategoryName" title="CategoryName" />
                    <Column field="UnitPrice" title="Price" width="80px" />
                    <Column field="UnitsInStock" title="In stock" width="80px" />
                    <Column field="Discontinued" width="120px"
                        cell={(props) => (
                            <td>
                                <input disabled type="checkbox" checked={props.dataItem[props.field]} />
                            </td>
                        )} />
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.querySelector('my-app')
);
```

We have tried to provide **data-grid="myGrid"** attribute to the grid but that doesn't seems to work. Could you please suggest what is the mistake here or what will be the solution.

Comment: Any suggestion guys ?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass prop using `camelCase` so it should be like this:

```
<Grid dataGrid="myGrid" />
```

And inside `Grid` you can specify it like this:

```
const Grid = ({dataGrid}) => (
   <div data-grid={dataGrid} />
)
```

Or you can just set `id` to the component `<Grid id="myGrid" />`

Comment: ok, i have tried the provided option, but seems it is not working.. while inspecting the components, i can't see the provided Ids/attributes